# Cascade/Count adding entry to the end of cell value

Tags: google-sheets

Google sheets function is showing current List as:

```
Thing
Thing
Thing
Otherthing
Otherthing
Otherthing
Otherthing
thisthing
thinghere
thinghere
```

I need it to be like bellow:

```
Thing1
Thing2
Thing3
Otherthing1
Otherthing2
Otherthing3
Otherthing4
thisthing1
thinghere1
thinghere2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If your list starts in A1, in B1:

```
=A1&countif(A$1:A1,A1)
```

and copy down to suit.